# A regex not working with grep

Tags: regex, grep

Just now I was looking for a regex that will detect string not enclosed in double quotes. I got  fabulous answer to that which worked in `javascript`. I am actually trying to run it using grep but it isn't working. Can anyone help me why this regex isn't working

Sample string : `"quick" "brown" fox jumps "over" "the" lazy dog`

I am trying to run : `echo "quick" "brown" fox jumps "over" "the" lazy dog | grep -e '(?<![\S"])([^"\s]+)(?![\S"])'`

It gives no output. How different are linux regexes from normal regexes. How can this be done?
Please help. Refer to this link: http://regexr.com?31eg3 for the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things, first you need to quote the whole string to echo, or the shell strips the double quotes. Then you are using perl-style regular expressions, so you need to tell grep to use them for matching with the `-P` option.

```
$ echo "quick" "brown" fox jumps "over" "the" lazy dog
quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
$ echo "quick" "brown" fox jumps "over" "the" lazy dog | grep -e '(?<![\S"])([^"\s]+)(?![\S"])'
$ echo '"quick" "brown" fox jumps "over" "the" lazy dog' | grep -e '(?<![\S"])([^"\s]+)(?![\S"])'
$ echo '"quick" "brown" fox jumps "over" "the" lazy dog' | grep -P -o -e '(?<![\S"])([^"\s]+)(?![\S"])'
fox
jumps
lazy
dog
```

Here I added `-o`, so it is clear what was matched.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the output of `echo`:

```
$ echo "quick" "brown" fox jumps "over" "the" lazy dog
quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Try this:

```
$ echo '"quick" "brown" fox jumps "over" "the" lazy dog'
```

Answer (score 0):

First correction, enclose your string into single quotes:

```
echo '"quick" "brown" fox jumps "over" "the" lazy dog'

user@machine:~$ echo '"quick" "brown" fox jumps "over" "the" lazy dog' 
"quick" "brown" fox jumps "over" "the" lazy dog
```

then use,
use -P option for PERL compatible regular expressions.

```
echo '"quick" "brown" fox jumps "over" "the" lazy dog' | grep -P -o '(?<![\S"])([^"\s]+)(?![\S"])'
fox
jumps
lazy
dog
```

Thanks to @lynxlynxlynx for the -o tip, else it just shows whole string with matches highlighted in other color.